# SVN Client vs Repository Browser

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-repository

If I have an SVN client installed on my machine, do I still need a Repository Browser? My understanding is that 'Repository Browser' is a read-only SVN client. Could someone throw some light on this?

Update - Adding more specific questions:

1. Do all SVN clients come with a Repository Browser?
2. Are 'Repository Browsers' available standalone, that would just allow you to browse through the SVN repo, but not check-in/check-out etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No. RepoBrowser in TSVN isn't read-only client for browsed repository, you can (if you have sufficient rights) change repository data from RepoBrowser
2. No. **Not all** SVN-clients have repobrowser feature (at least CLI Subversion client doesn't have it)
3. Yes, *to some degree*. I don't know special RepositoryBrowser-only desktop applications, but such Webapps exist in the Net (WebSVN, ViewVC).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure entirely sure what you're asking, given that this is tagged with TortoiseSVN, and the Repository Browser is a component of that client, which is an integral part of the UI, not something you would download separately or optionally. If you want to browse the repository, you would use the repository browser. (After installing TortoiseSVN, it's in the TortoiseSVN context menu, as "Repo-browser".)

Thus, I suppose the literal answer would be "yes, but you don't need to download it separately, as it's part of the install."

Comment: from few of the blogs i read, i got an understanding that there are 'Repository Browser' web applications available, which could allow you to access SVN repository without having a client installed in your machine. Since i am new to tortoiseSVN, i didn't realize it has a component called 'Repo Browser'. 1. Does all SVNClients come with a Repository Browser ?  2. Are 'Repository Browsers' available as standalone, that would just allow you to browser through, but not check-in/check-out..etc ?

Comment: 1. I have no idea if "all" svn client have a repository browser, but it seems likely that at least most of them would. 

2. Since you mentioned a web application - it's pretty common for svn *servers* to have the ability to also serve their data read-only as an http server, if you were to point your browser to the location you normally connect to with your svn client. 
I don't know of any standalone thick client apps, but I also haven't looked, as TortoiseSVN does everything I would need.